# Create Dynamic Url at Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I have an initialState and a dynamic URL and async thunk for axios

I want to change URL query parameter according to a key in initial state.

```
?query=${initialState.category}
```

category changes but URL fetches data with unchanged category (it uses initial key not modified key)

```
const initialState = {
  category: "burger",
  products: [],
  isLoading: true,
  categories :{
    burger:"burger",
    kebab:"kebab",
    chicken:"chicken",
    pizza:"pizza",
    fish:"fish",
    vegan:"vegan",
    salad:"salad",
    pasta:"pasta",
    steak:"steak",
    dessert:"dessert",
    waffle:"waffle"
}

};

const url = `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/menuItems/search?query=${initialState.category}&number=10&apiKey=API_KEY`;

export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/getProducts",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => { 
    
    try {
      const response = await axios(url);
      console.log(response);
      return await response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error: error.message });
    }
  }
);

export const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "product",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    pickCategory: (state, action) => {
      state.category = action.payload;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

that line is static as value in initialState is not mutated:

```
const url = `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/menuItems/search?query=${initialState.category}&number=10&apiKey=API_KEY`;
```

you need to move that constant inside getProducts thunk as thunk has an access to current store:

```
...
async (_, thunkAPI) => { 
 const {category} = thunkApi.getState()
 const url = `https://api.spoonacular.com/food/menuItems/search? 
  query=${category}&number=10&apiKey=API_KEY`;
}
...
```